# HTML form within an image

Tags: html, css

How can i put and an html form (text box and buttons) within an image (jpg). Please provide the css, html code.

Note: Image should be in the background and should be in full dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use this trick:

```
<form style="position: relative;">
    <img src="mypicture.jpg" border="0" />
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> 
       Input here... <input type="text" /><br />
       Input here... <input type="text" /><br />
       Input here... <input type="text" /><br />
       Input here... <input type="text" /><br />
       Input here... <input type="text" /><br />
       <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live test case is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/9UcZg/

Edit: in order to have the form contents centered, either hard code the width like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center; width: 450px;">
```

(updated test case: http://jsfiddle.net/9UcZg/2/)

Or use JavaScript to calculate the width "on the fly":

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var oImage = document.getElementById("MyFormBackground");
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("MyFormContents");
    var totalWidth = oImage.offsetWidth;
    var contentsWidth = oDiv.offsetWidth;
    oDiv.style.left = parseInt((totalWidth - contentsWidth) / 2) + "px";
}
```

For this to work you'll have to alter the HTML a bit, adding `id` to the image and the container div, here is the updated test case: http://jsfiddle.net/9UcZg/3/

Comment: @Shadow: how do I center align the form ?? It should come right at the center of the image.

Comment: @Anand try changing the containing DIV to this: `<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center;">` if working I'll edit my answer otherwise let me know and I'll dig further..

Comment: @Anand see my edit.. most simple is putting the width of the image or if you don't know that width in advance, use the JS solution.

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean with 'within an image'?
do you want to use the image as form-background?
then something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.formWithBackground {
background-image:url("url to image");
background-repeate:no-repeat;
background-position:...
}
</style>
...
<body>...
<form class="formWithBackground">
<input type="text".../><button>send</button>
</form>
....
```

should help
regards
 gerhard

Comment: its ok. but the problem with the code is that image hieght becomes same as the forms height. Can u optimise the code so that the image comes in its ful dimensions??

Comment: yeah - the problem with css backgrounds is that they come 'as is' if the container is smaller than the image - the image will not be fully visible - if the container is larger - the image may be too small (you may have to repeat it horizonally/vertically). the solution mentioned above (container with relative position) is quite smart and should solve your problem. regards

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a div, and give the div a background image.

```
<style type="text/css">
#picture {
    background-image:url(myimage.jpg)
}
</style>

<div id="picture">

<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but the image hieght becomes same as the forms height. Can u optimise the code so that the image comes in its ful dimensions??

Comment: do you mean the image is too small? You can't resize the image in the CSS, so you would have to change your image, or restructure the code with layers.

Comment: no.. the image gets truncated in its height according o the height of the form. Can it come full size? try once.. u will see.

Comment: @Anand just specify a height and width for the form, so that it has the same size as the image.  It won't be truncated that way.  This is a way better solution than the accepted response.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to have the jpeg image as the background of the element that contains the form fields.

CSS:

```
.myformbox {
  background-image:url(myimage.jpg);
  height:100px;  /*or whatever the height of the image is*/
  width:100px;   /*ditto*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='myformbox'>
  <form ....>
    ....input fields here....
  </form>
</div>
```

...or something like that.

I note your edit which says "image should be in full dimensions". That is still ambiguous language: do you mean "the box needs to be the full size of the image", or "the image needs to scale to the size of the box"?

For the first of those, see above, where I've added height and width parameters to the CSS.

For the second one however, you have a problem, which is that background image scaling isn't currently supported by CSS (yet!). Solutions to this are a bit more complex, but if this is the question you're asking, [here is a page that might help](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/).