# How to add form inside an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website. I want to add my form on the right side of image.This is a one of example for that[image: This is a one of example for that] 
My form and image are showed separately. I used inline style attribute for form but nothing happen. how can i do this?

Comment: insert some of your code .

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518817/html-form-within-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as background to body. Then add the form to the right side as position absolute.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?